# Writing file while __desctruct() function

Tags: php, fwrite, magic-methods

I have found that it is impossible to write (`file_put_contents` or simple `fwrite`) inside `__destruct()` of PHP class, how to invoke that? full function:

```
    function __destruct()
    {
        foreach($this->data as $name=>$value) $$name=$value;    

        if(count($this->modules)>0)
        {   foreach($this->modules as $name=>$value) 
            {   
                ob_start();
                include $value;
                $content=ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                $$name = $content;
            }
        }                   
        ob_start();

        include $this->way;

        $content = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        $fp = fopen('cache.txt', 'w+');
        fputs($fp, $content);
        fclose($fp);

        echo $content; 

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have permission to write to where you're writing? A quick test shows me that I can indeed call `file_put_contents()` in `__destruct()`.  Please post your code.

Comment: By the way, I would consider writing files in a destructor to be a "_side effect_". Document the behavior very explicitly in your code to save the sanity of future programmers working on it (yourself included)

Comment: thanks for answer, all writing in `__construct()` but not in `__destruct()` maybe because im using `ob_start();` and getting content, but i was trying also inside the buffer and not inside.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's possible the problem you have is that you're still referencing the object inside of your destruct().

You should have no problems writing to a file in a __destruct at all. The below example proves it:

```
<?php
    class TestDestruct{
       function __construct(){
          $this->f = 'test';
       }

       function __destruct(){
          print 'firing';
          $fp = fopen('test.txt', 'w+');
          fputs($fp, 'test');
          fclose($fp);
      }
    }


$n = new TestDestruct();
empty($n);
```

Remember the destruct will only be fired once there are no references to that object. so if you were to be doing something like 
`fputs($fp, $this->f)`

then it's not going to work.

Comment: same as before when i added in any part of `__destruct()` of my function

Comment: i dont pass the object, only text or variable, also file dont create at all.

Comment: Try my example and see if it works.
If my sample does not work then it sounds to me like a permission issue.

Comment: Downvote because you can use `$this` in `__destruct()` without any issues. Even in the PHP manual's example it's done. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php